# SQL: Add column with incremental id to SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a simple query like:

```
SELECT name FROM people;
```

The `people` table does not a have unique id column. I want to add to the query result a column `id` with incremental `int` starting from 0 or 1 (it doesn't matter). How can one achieve this? (postgresql DB)

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` if SQL Server

Comment: @lad2025 actually postgresql

Comment: @lad2025: window functions are nothing special to SQL Server.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5bb81/2/0)

```
SELECT 
  name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id
FROM people;
```

**EDIT:**

Difference between `ORDER BY 1` vs `ORDER BY column_name`

[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a227e/4/1)

```
SELECT 
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id
FROM people;

/* Execution Plan */
QUERY PLAN WindowAgg (cost=83.37..104.37 rows=1200 width=38)
-> Sort (cost=83.37..86.37 rows=1200 width=38)
**Sort Key: name**
-> Seq Scan on people (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=38)

SELECT 
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS id
FROM people;

/* Execution Plan */
QUERY PLAN WindowAgg (cost=0.00..37.00 rows=1200 width=38)
-> Seq Scan on people (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=38)
```

In second case there is no sort operation.

You can also write second query as:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id
FROM people;
```

**Why people write `ORDER BY 1` in windowed functions?**

Because in some dialects it is required and `ORDER BY 1` acts like placeholder.

Oracle:

> ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

```
SELECT 
  name,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS id
FROM people;
```

TSQL:

> The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

```
SELECT 
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS id
FROM people;
```

Comment: What is the difference between ORDER BY 1 or column name?

Answer (score 2):

The `row_number` window function should fit the bill:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1), *
FROM   people
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `row_number()` function at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need it only when the query is run, you can use `row_number`.

```
select row_number() over(order by name) as id, name
from people
```